# Message "Did not have IAM permissions to process tags on AWS::KMS::Key resource" When Creating KMS Key Using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

While creating a new KMS key using Cloudformation I see this message in the "Status Reason" column:

> Did not have IAM permissions to process tags on AWS::KMS::Key resource

The cloudformation stack seems to be created correctly, but I was wondering what I can do to prevent this message from being shown?

I'm using the following Cloudformation template to create a KMS key:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "KMS key"
Outputs:
  KeyArn:
    Value: !Sub "${KmsKey.Arn}"
Resources:
  KmsKey:
    Properties:
      Description: "KMS key"
      Enabled: true
      EnableKeyRotation: false
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: "Enable IAM User Permissions"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
            Action: "kms:*"
            Resource: "*"          
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Key"
  KmsKeyAlias:    
    Properties:
      AliasName: "alias/KmsKey"
      TargetKeyId: !Ref "KmsKey"
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Alias"
```

The role I use to create the resource allows the following actions:

```
- Action:
    - kms:Create*
    - kms:List*
  Effect: "Allow"
  Resource: "*"
- Action:
    - kms:Describe*
    - kms:Enable*
    - kms:Put*
    - kms:Update*
    - kms:Get*
    - kms:Decrypt
    - kms:Encrypt
  Effect: "Allow"
  Resource:
    - "arn:aws:kms:*:*:key/*"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My role was missing the following action:

```
- kms:TagResource
```